# Unable to send JSON data to python from JQUERY

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I am trying to build a chatbot in Flask-python which needs to interact with javascript for connecting to a URL to bring the data.

I am able to send and receive strings from javascript to Python but now i am facing issue when i am trying to send JSON data from javascript to python.

I have tried multiple things like using ajax call in JS and using request.json in python but couldn't succeed.

Below is the code i am using sending strings

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getBotResponse(rawText) {
        $.getJSON('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/', {q: rawText}, 
            function(jsndata) {
            var intent = jsndata.topScoringIntent.intent;
                }
                $.get("/get", { intt: intent }).done(function(data) 
                    {
                        $('<div class="botText">'+data+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
                        $('.chat_body').scrollTop($('.chat_body')[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

And below is the python code for receiving the string and return answer:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    jsondata = request.args.get('intt')
    print(type(jsondata))
    print(jsondata)
```

This is working fine but when i trying to send the json in the same way i am getting errors like `Internal Server Error` and when i tried ajax it said `BAD Request`.

How i can send the json data through a variable from javascript to python?

NOTE: i am familiar with using urllib request/https requests methods in python to connect to URL and get the json data but my company's policies are not allowing that so need to find some way i can send the data from javascript.

Comment: you are importing jquery twice , just remove one link and try

Comment: You can just stringify it and send it, parse it in the other end.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be getting the issue because `$.get(..., { intt: XXX })` is expecting a string in place of the `XXX`, not an object.

The easiest way to solve this is to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
{ intt: JSON.stringify(intent) }
```

And then parse the JSON from string in Python

The better way to do this, of course, is to POST the JSON, rather than pass it as a URL query. URL queries can have length restrictions and speed limitations.